# Why the canvas position is affected by screen resolution in Unity?

Tags: unity

I meet an issue that if I use 1024x768 resolution to run my game, the position(not local position) of the canvas is -1 in z axis. On the other hand, with resolution of 1136x640, the position is -5 in z axis(I never use code or anything to change its position). Is there any reason to cause this issue?

Comment: Can you share how you found out about this? Is the canvas just a UI Canvas? How do you know the Z position? From the inspector? Or only when you build the game?

Comment: Do you have a canvas scaler script in play?

Comment: I printed position's x,y and z in run-time. And I have a canvas scaler script in play.

Comment: Try using an orthographic camera, see if the issue is still there. (I'm thinking it has to do with the perspective camera and how the canvas scaler is interacting with it.)

Comment: orthographic camera doesn't have this issue, I tried

Answer (score 1):

you can set the canvas scaler to a constant pixel or physical size rather than scale with screen size. Set the panel to stretch and then you can set the pixels from each edge and it will fix your issue.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I set it to constant physical size mode and it's working!

Comment: But why it's working?

Comment: @OtakuFitness Constant Pixel Size makes UI elements retain the same size in pixels regardless of screen size, while Scale WithScreenSize makes UI elements bigger the bigger the screen is.